# JQ how to merge multiple objects in an array into one

Tags: arrays, json, object, addition, jq

A little more sophisticated as my question mentioned below.
I learned to use arrays more, but it screws things up too.

Input:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": "c",
      "d": "e"
    },
    {
      "b": "f",
      "d": "g"
    }
  ],
  "h": [
    {
      "b": "c",
      "i": "j"
    },
    {
      "b": "f",
      "i": "k"
    }
  ]
}
```

desired output:

```
{
  "l": [
    {
      "b": "c",
      "d": "e",
      "i": "j"
    },
    {
      "b": "f",
      "d": "g",
      "i": "k"
    }
  ]
}
```

Things that I've tried, based up on [JQ How to merge multiple objects into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491317/jq-how-to-merge-multiple-objects-into-one)

```
{ x: [ inputs | .a[] | { (.h[]): .i } ] | add}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to a simple solution is `transpose`:

```
[.a, .h]
| transpose
| map(add)
| {l: .}
```

Comment: Tx for keeping count!