# merge multiple lists with jq into single list

Tags: json, jq

I have a aws cli bash loop generating multiple json lists, containing dictionaries.
I can't get jq to merge the lists into one large list with all the dictionaries.

e.g.

```
[  { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" },
   { "key1": "value3", "key2": "value4" }
]
[  { "key1": "value5", "key2": "value6" }
]
[  { "key1": "value7" }
]
```

this gets piped to jq and i would like it to be merged to

```
[ { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" },
  { "key1": "value3", "key2": "value4" },
  { "key1": "value5", "key2": "value6" },
  { "key1": "value7" }
]
```

Comment: The snippet is not valid JSON. Properly quote the values in the input shown

Comment: No, it isn't - https://jsonlint.com/, try pasting it here

Comment: `jq -s add filename` works fine.

Comment: I checked it there,   the 2nd bit (result) is valid, the first is just 3 json lists, that is the issue. The bash loop runs aws cli and gets a new json list back everytime, i am trying to merge them into one using jq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have jq 1.5, the solution posted here:

[JQ How to merge multiple objects into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491317/jq-how-to-merge-multiple-objects-into-one)

provides the basic technique of using `jq -n` with the `inputs` operator.

```
cat FILE | jq -n '[inputs|.[]]'
```

does the trick.  `[inputs]` glues the multiple results into a single list and the '.[]' strips the extra level of list that was added.

Answer (score -2):

i hacked a fix using awk, there must me a way to do it with jq.

```
| awk 'NR==1{print}NR>1{sub(/^]/,"");sub(/^\[/,",");print}END{print "]"}' \
```

What it does,

1. skip first line "[" (leave it in place)
2. remove all "^]" at start of lines
3. replace "[" at start of line with "," new list starting
4. at the end close it all with "]"